# How to use Eclipse UOMo (Units of Measurement) in standalone project?

Tags: java, eclipse, units-of-measurement, jsr-275, uomo

I'm trying to use the UOMo java library in eclipse:
http://www.eclipse.org/uomo

I've installed it correctly (or at least I believe I have) via Help -> Install New Software..., dropped the repository link in, went through it all, was prompted to restart eclipse after installing the software.

My problem is I have no idea how to use it.  I've created a project and had a good dig around in the build path config.  I can't find how to include UOMoin the project (obviously not doing is preventing my code compiling).

Just to be clear; I have read the tutorial, but it is based around the project being a plugin project.  I'm integrating it into a pre existing code base which isn't plugin based, and I don't really know enough about plugin projects to happily convert.

As a second, more broader question; how can I learn more about how developers share their code through repositories?  I always feel confused and a bit overwhelmed with eclipse as it seems to have a lot of way of including code.  Up until now I've been downloading jars and including them directly.  Sorry I understand this question is a bit more fluffy, but I feel like I don't have a grasp on the basic methods of using repositories to include 3rd party code.

Comment: Look at the UoMo tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/uomo/documents/EclipseUOMoTutorial.pdf From the tutorial this look like it is intended for plugin development

Comment: Ah I was wondering if that is avoidable.  I'm attempting to integrate it into a mature java code base I've already got to use it for validation of units (i.e. if someone enters a unit string, is that a valid unit).  What exactly is the difference between a java project and a plug in project?

Comment: Eclipse plugins will only run in an Eclipse RCP (such as Eclipse itself) and generally depend on other plugins

Comment: So does this means I can't use Uomo unless my project is a plugin project?  Sorry for being dense but what does it mean for my code if I convert it to a plugin project?

Comment: From the look of the download, yes it would have to be a plugin project as part of an Eclipse RCP. Check the documentation on the site to see if it has anything on using it a different way.

Comment: You can also ask in the UOMo forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/197/