# Where can I find a JSR-275 replacement?

Tags: java, jsr

[JSR-275](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=275) has been discontinued and will soon be removed from the javax namespace as far as I can tell from googling around. Supposedly there is a replacement at [org.unitsofmeasurement](http://www.unitsofmeasurement.org/) but the API seems to be quite different from JSR-275. Supposedly [jscience](http://jscience.org/) is a replacement but there doesn't seem to be a maven repository with artefacts (like a JAR) that can be relied upon.

Am I missing something or is this just one of those things where I need to download source, build my own JAR, and ignore the chaos out on the Internet?

And if I do that, what are the options? Is there a good option for source download or to I need to just grab a copy of the something like jsr-275 1.0-beta-2 jar and stash it away in my own repo? This seems a bit risky since a future Java upgrade (Java 9?) could potentially break compatibility with some old jars.

How are you handling this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224122/which-jsr-275-units-implementation-should-be-used

Comment: Indeed I have and that info is out of date. Since that time not much has happened with the JSR-275 implementations as far as I can see. But I am hoping that other users of these classes would explain how they are dealing with the problem today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking for a JSR-275 replacement, I found Eclipse UOMo http://www.eclipse.org/uomo/.

It is still at the incubation stage, but it seems very promising.

Don't know if they have a Maven repository, but it is fully OSGi compatible, which is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The official replacement of JSR-275 is [JSR-363 Units of Measurement API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=363). There are different implementations (see also [JSR 363 Implementation and Adoption](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/ec-public/materials/2017-05-08/JSR363_IMPL_JCP_EC_May_2017.pdf)), I would recommend the reference implementation [Indriya](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya) as it seems a stable Java 8 (2.0) or even Java 9/12/14 implementation (2.1) available from Maven Central.

More details can be found on the official [Units of Measurement](http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io) project site.